# Argument 3 passed to Sonata\Twig\Extension\TemplateExtension::__construct()

Tags: php, symfony, sonata, twig-extension

Since updating to Symfony 4.2 from 4.1.8, I keep getting the following error:

```
 22:00:39 CRITICAL  [php] Argument 3 passed to Sonata\Twig\Extension\TemplateExtension::__construct() must be an instance of Sonata\CoreBundle\Model\Adapter\AdapterInterface, instance of Sonata\Doctrine\Adapter\AdapterChain given, called in /home/kostya/projects/php/www/hillel/sf_store/var/cache/dev/ContainerOrMv7ZL/srcApp_KernelDevDebugContainer.php on line 1265 ["exception" => Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError { …}]
!!  
!!  In TemplateExtension.php line 40:
!!                                                                                 
!!    Argument 3 passed to Sonata\Twig\Extension\TemplateExtension::__construct()  
!!     must be an instance of Sonata\CoreBundle\Model\Adapter\AdapterInterface, i  
!!    nstance of Sonata\Doctrine\Adapter\AdapterChain given, called in /home/kost  
!!    ya/projects/php/www/hillel/sf_store/var/cache/dev/ContainerOrMv7ZL/srcApp_K  
!!    ernelDevDebugContainer.php on line 1265
```

Does anyone have an idea how to fix it?

Comment: What does the interface expect the class to receive for argument 3? (Sonata\CoreBundle\Model\Adapter\AdapterInterface)  a string, integer, array, object, boolean etc..

Comment: I think this is a bug while updating symfony. me too faced the problem. But not solved yet. The bug may be in sonata-project/core-bundle (3.13.2)

Answer (score 1):

Its a bug in sonata-project/core-bundle (3.13.2)

Check this GIT: https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataCoreBundle/issues/613

Comment: @Bsquare This is a valid answer. Noting it's a known bug and providing a link to the bug report is helpful. Nothing more needs to be added. See [this meta answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/321457/7296893) for further guidance.

Comment: OK, I understand.

Answer (score 0):

> Updating sonata-project/doctrine-extensions (1.1.2 => 1.1.3):
>   Downloading (100%) Updating sonata-project/core-bundle (3.13.2 =>
>   3.13.4): Downloading (100%)

Yes, they fixed it today!! Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain further what you did to make it work again?